# USB communication keeps disconnecting because of power dip/spike

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, usb, usb-device, ups

I've got a question. I've got CNC router that's connected by USB to a desktop computer. We're in an old building, and wiring is not optimal :) I'm not an expert, but I think too many rooms are on the same group.

My CNC machine disconnects every few minutes/hours. This happens when someone else turns on; a light, a water cooker, a vacuum cleaner, coffee machine, heck even the radio. This does not even have to be in the same room.

In a approach to fix this I've:

- put one machine (cnc or pc) on a different group
- put both machines on a different group
- added a powered usb cable (5 or 10m)(the pc is a few meters away)

But no result. **So my question is:**

- Do you know something to fix this?
- would adding a UPS to the pc and/or cnc help? (are they quick enough to catch the dip/spike?)
- Could or should a I add capacitors to the usb power wires. (if so, which)
- Or even better, what is the exact cause for it all to crash. :)

### -- edit --

The setup is as following

- [CNC Router from X-Carve](https://www.inventables.com/technologies/x-carve)

  - The machine (execpt the spindel) is powerd by the [x-controller](https://www.inventables.com/technologies/x-controller-kit)
  - it has an internal 24V 400W power supply
- The CNC is connected to the PC with a [USB cable](https://www.allekabels.nl/usb-verlengkabel/4965/1049889/usb-verlengkabel-met-versterker.html?gclid=CNjzgpas1-ICFZTodwod29kChw)

  - The USB cable has it's own (extra) external power adapter (5V 0.25 amp), a powered usb cable.
- The desktop computer sends the commands to the CNC router

  - The pc has, from the top of my head, a power supply of around 200W

When a power drop occurs the CNC freezes. This is most likely because the connection to the pc is reset and it stops receiving commands.

Note, the power drop is always also noticed on other electronical devices.

- Radio/Stereo speakers make a crispy/ticking sound on a power drop
- Some people experience the mouse cursor jump a few cm on the screen on a power drop.

Comment: You talk about the USB cable and USB power. But the CNC isn't powered through the USB cable, is it? Does it have its own supply? What supply is it? Does the entire CNC machine shut down, or just the USB peripheral seem to disconnect itself? Can you describe the whole hardware setup, including links to parts decription?

Comment: yeah, of all devices likely to interfere with the USB connection, your CNC machine itself is the by far likeliest; I'm almost certain the wiring of your building is not to blame.

Comment: @dim, Would the edit answer your questions?

Comment: It is clearer. Since the CNC has its own supply, I doubt the USB 5V from the PC (or the cable adapter) is actually used for anything on the CNC, except maybe detecting that the cable is plugged. You can guess whether the problem comes from the USB 5V voltage or the mains supply by putting a 4.5V battery as the USB cable power source instead of the external adapter, and see if you still have the problem. But it likely  comes from the mains supply of the CNC. There is probably a place within the CNC controller where putting a big capacitor would solve the problem, but it is hard to tell where.

Comment: um, is the PC properly grounded? Might be your USB cable's outer shielding acting as an antenna if it isn't. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Does it fail when both pc and tool share the same power outlet i.e. you have a surge problem causing ground bounce on either pc or tool which, in turn pushes stupid currents down the USB cable and breaks the comms link?

Comment: @dim, ah I could try it out with the battery. But I might have to sacrifice a power connector for that :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I think so. I think the pc is properly grounded. The computer and the socket are grounded. I did read something about static electricity from the vacuum. vacuuming the dust. But I've grounded the plastic hose to the radiator.

Comment: @Andyaka, you think it might be a short? It only happens when another machine causes a power spike/drop

Comment: I think that trying the powered USB cable was a good choice.  However, we struggled with a similar issue and discovered that not all USB cables are created equally, and finally found a high-quality, optically isolated setup that would allow us to use our camera over a similar distance in the presence of moving stepper motors.  This was in a system where everything was already using the same AC circuit, with the computer system using a UPS (but an 'offline'/consumer-grade version).  I believe the cable was quite expensive, so this solution may not fit your budget.  Slow USB only.

Answer (score 3):

> "is your PC properly grounded"?

I would say that your problem is that your equipment is "too much grounded". Likely you have several ground loops that create ground spikes as you turn on-off other equipment, through so-called "ground bounces". Try to power your PC and CNC from the same power strip (even is you need a long power cable to your CNC, and don't ground anything other that the native ground wire at the AC outlet. USB has very limited tolerance to common-mode offsets, 2-3V maybe, so the right grounding and correct de-coupling of the USB cable shield is critical for noise tolerance. It is very likely that the router has wrong/suboptimal shield schematics at the USB connector.

So, all-individual power cables without any extra grounds might solve your problem.

The other method would be to put the controlling PC in near proximity to the router itself, and communicate with PC remotely via a Wi-Fi port. This will provide good isolation from your noisy environment.

I don't know of a good optically-isolated USB link that would operate at USB 2.0 HS. There are a fairly-well engineered optical cables made professionally by [Corning Communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/285510/117785). Fiber-optics provide good signal fidelity over long distances, but the power/ground is not truly isolated in their design. So ground loops might be still an issue.

Comment: ahh, I'm starting to understand the concept.  (1) All the equipment to one wall socket is easily done. I'll start with that! (2) I'll look for a usb over wifi/bluetooth solution. But I think that might cause troubles with the latency/feedback for the (safety)sensors on the CNC Router. (3) I'll dive into Opto-isolator usb cables. Maybe I could easily build one myself? Maybe just a man-in-the-middle solution. And plug it in between. I would, maybe, only need the data cables and not the power cables on the usb.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after upgrading my desktop CNC machine with a better spindle motor. In my case, the PC is close to the CNC machine, about 18" away, and was always plugged into the same 120AC circuit. The motor upgrade introduced a ton more line noise, and RF emissions to the equipment vicinity. After the upgrade, automated jobs would fail regularly if they were longer than a few gcode instructions. As a test, I wrapped the USB cable around a c-clamp to choke HF in the USB cable and it worked perfectly. I plan to get back the proper use of my c-clamp by replacing it with a ferrite core but haven't done that yet. Nevertheless, the solution's been working perfectly for months.[image]

Comment: I Always love seeing a field expedient solution!

Comment: Last weekend I finally got around to getting a ferrite torus to use instead of the c-clamp in the above picture, and I happened to find a shorter, 1m, USB cable. I tried it and it's been working perfectly.  It doesn't sound like shortening the cable length is an option for @Tim, but maybe an option for others.